# Jquery Kenburner Slider creating mask 10px too short

Tags: jquery, slider

apologies for the ambiguous question title.

I have a Jquery Slider ([Ken Burner](http://codecanyon.net/item/kenburner-slider-jquery-plugin/1249801)) purchased from Code Canyon.

The problem i'm having is that the slider creates a mask `div` via the Jquery that automatically detects the width. However the mask is always 10px not wide enough. I'm not overly savvy with Javascript so i was hoping one of you may know the answer or how to fix the issue.

See my site [here](http://devsite77.clickdealer.co.uk).

Any input greatly apreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who did have a look;

```
opt.width=top_container.width()-0;
opt.height=top_container.height()-0;
```

The above numeric values were set to -10 so logically i changed these values! Thanks to anyone who might have looked into it.